# Kernel Install Issue: New USB Device Found, Product: USB Optical Mouse Repeating

Tags: kernel

First time poster here.

I am updating to Linux kernel version 4.6.3 and used Lilo to install it.

I am running Ubuntu version 16.04lts.

When I went to select the new kernel everything started out fine, but it is currently doing something a little weird. It keeps printing out the following:

```
[ XXXX, YYYYYY] usb 3-14: newlow-speed USB device number ZZ using xhci_hcd

[ XXXX, YYYYYY] usb 3-14: new device found, idVendor 04ca, idProduct=0061

[ XXXX, YYYYYY] usb 3-14: new device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=0

[ XXXX, YYYYYY] usb 3-14: Product: USB Optical Mouse

[ XXXX, YYYYYY] usb 3-14: Manufacturer: PixArt

[ XXXX, YYYYYY] usb 3-14: USB disconnect, device number ZZ
```

where ZZ has been slowly increasing from 1-38 (currently it's at 38 anyway, who knows where it will stop.) and XXXX, YYYYYY are different for each ZZ.

This isn't normal, right?

What should I do?

Thanks for your time and feedback.

Comment: I found a very similar thing in my syslog :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this does not happen with the official kernel (currently 4.4.0-28), you have your answer.

Mainline kernels are not 100% compatible with Ubuntu, they are not recommended and they should not be installed unless there are certain hardware issues the official kernel does not support.

Additionally, mainline kernels lack the `image-extra` package which contains drivers released by Canonical.

Answer (score 0):

Your Lite-On PixArt OEM mouse is still unknown in the Linux kernel `usbhid` quirks in kernel v5.0-rc5. PixArt USB Optical Mouse ICs have a **HW bug**. Their **buffer overflows**, firmware crashes, and they reconnect if they are not always polled. So they require `HID_QUIRK_ALWAYS_POLL` (`0x00000400`) or the `gpm` service to be enabled to function properly.

**Basics**: https://github.com/sriemer/fix-linux-mouse

If you could test kernel boot parameter `usbhid.quirks=0x04ca:0x0061:0x00000400`, then I could prepare the patch for the upstream Linux kernel. TIA